# Route ErrorException for Local Laravel Project but not Production Project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

On my local Laravel project if I access the url `http://local.website.com/share/show/372/3149,3150` I get the error:

> [2017-03-15 14:05:16] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: class' in /home/vagrant/Code/RP/storage/framework/views/e48b285e80e2612c5de297f7900a6e0c9933aec4.php:74
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/vagrant/Code/RP/storage/framework/views/e48b285e80e2612c5de297f7900a6e0c9933aec4.php(74): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/home/vagrant/C...', 74, Array)

But on my production Laravel project if I access the url `http://website.com/share/show/372/3149,3150` I dont get any error and the view shows.

The production url points to my live VPS Cent OS. My local setup is on Windows 10 but running inside Homestead. Both projects use the exact same code.

*What could be going wrong here? Do I need to clear artisans cache? Any advice would be extremely helpful.*

**Edit:** Adding `e48b285e80e2612c5de297f7900a6e0c9933aec4.php` line of code causing the error:

```
<td class="text-center status<?=$class?>"> <!-- Line 74 -->
    <?=$res?>
</td>
```

Comment: Could you show use line 74 in `e48b285e80e2612c5de297f7900a6e0c9933aec4.php`?

Comment: @DestinatioN please see edit with the code

Comment: From where did you get that `$class` variable value

Comment: `<td class="text-center status{{$class or "None"}}>"> <!-- Line 74 -->
    {{$res}}
</td>`

Comment: @kaiogita No, because `e48b285e80e2612c5de297f7900a6e0c9933aec4.php` is the compiled view by laravel. In the uncompiled view he already has used `{{` and `}}` to wrap his php

Comment: please i want to see more view code

Answer (score -1):

Check if your `$class` variable is defined from your view or  has been pass from 
your controller like

```
return view('myview', compact('class')); //or
return view('greeting')->with('class', 'English');
```

Tip: Use blade when passing data to views

```
{{$class}}
```

Comment: i was downvote because i was giving you a heads up that you might have mistake with the your passing of data?